# Amending an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have been trying over the past day to read and amend this xml

```
<TimeSeriesDocument xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:Test">
<DocumentIdentification v="ZDAE_02417b6a-477a-a-4aa19e1c4712"/>
<TimeSeries>
<Period>
  <TimeInterval v="12" />
  <Resolution v="PT1H" />
  <Interval>
    <Pos v="17" />
    <Qty v="0" />
  </Interval>
  <Interval>
    <Pos v="19" />
    <Qty v="10" />
  </Interval>
</Period>
</TimeSeries>
</TimeSeriesDocument>
```

I want to amend each Qty within each Interval within the period

I have been using Descendants but i'm struggling to loop over each Interval and pick and change the Qty

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(test.xml);
var periods = doc.Descendants("TimeSeriesDocument/TimeSeries").Select(e => new { name = e.Element("Period").Value });
```

Can you please help?

Comment: What type of project are you trying to use to read the xml file?

Answer (score 1):

A sample console application to loop through Qty nodes and set new value for v attribute:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load("Sample.xml");

        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "urn:Test");

        var intervalNodes = document.SelectNodes("//ns:Interval", nsmgr);
        foreach(XmlNode node in intervalNodes)
        {
            var quantityNode = node.SelectSingleNode("./ns:Qty", nsmgr);
            quantityNode.Attributes["v"].Value = "New Value";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:Test";

XElement doc = XElement.Load("file.xml");

var periods = doc.Descendants(ns + "Period");
var intervals = periods.Elements(ns + "Interval");

foreach (var qty in intervals.Elements(ns + "Qty"))
{
    qty.Attribute("v").Value = "42";
}
```